# XSL, issue with getting xsl:value-of inside a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, value-of

I've got an XML with diferent nodes:

```
<INFORME>
  <Assignatura>
     <Nom_materia>Física</Nom_materia>
  </Assignatura>
  <Assignatura>
     <Nom_materia>Informàtica</Nom_materia>
  </Assignatura>
</INFORME>
```

and, inside of the `for-each`, I want to get access to the previous node. 
I want to do something like this, and logically it doesnt work.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Assignatura">
  <xsl if text="Nom_materia = Assignatura[position()-1]/Nom_materia">
    do something...
....
```

It would be something very simple I think, but i don't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your context node is INFORME:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Assignatura">
  <xsl:if test="Nom_materia = preceding-sibling::Assignatura[1]/Nom_materia">
    do something...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks raffazizzi;

but, i don't know exactly what i'm getting from the preceding-sibling;
it seems is getting random "nom_materia";  but: the for-each is sorted:
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="nom_materia"/>

may this affect on that? thank you!

Comment: Well, the preceding-sibling axis will get the node that precedes the current node *in the tree*, not in the for each order.
Looking up the previous item in the iteration is a different matter, and I think it will require that you create a variable containing the ordered elements first.